# Obj-C, how do I make my segmented control narrower in IB?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I can't seem to make my segmented control, which is within a tableview smaller?

I'm not sure what fixed and the width, which is default to auto does?

I can't change the width from 320 either.

Heres a screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried checking `Fixed` to manually input a fixed width?

Comment: It accepts the values but it doesn't change on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIKit is going to resize a header view to be the full width of the table. Put the segment control in a view, and make that view the header view.

Answer (score 0):

I find that when you put custom controls in a table view header or footer it is often best to place them on top of a separate UIView and make that UIView the actual header/footer.